# Override field in the input before passing to the next state in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Say I have 3 states, A -> B -> C. Let's assume inputs to A include a field called `names` which is of type List and each element contains two fields `firstName` and `lastName`. State B will process the inputs to A and and return a response called `newLastName`. If I want to override every element in `names` such that `names[i].lastName = newLastName` before passing this input to state C, is there an built-in syntax to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You control the events passed to the next task in a Step Function with three defintion attributes: `ResultPath` and `OutputPath` on leaving one task and `InputPath` on entering the next one.

You have to first understand how the event to the next task is crafted by a State Machine, and each of the 3 above parameters changes it.

You have to at least have Result Path. This is the key in the event that the output of your lambda will be placed under. so `ResultPath="$.my_path"` would result in a json object that has a top level key of my_path with the value equal to whatever is outputted from the lambda.

If this is the only attribute, it is tacked onto whatever the input was. So if your Input event was a json object with keys `original_key1` and `some_other_key` your output with just the above result path would be:

```
{
    "original_key_1": some value,
    "some_other_key": some other value,
    "my_path": the output of your lambda
}
```

Now if you add OutputPath, this cuts off everything OTHER than the path (AFTER adding the result path!) in the next output.

If you added `OutputPath="$.my_path"` you would end up with a json of:

```
{ output of your lambda }
```

(your output better be a json comparable object, like a python dict!)

InputPath does the same thing ... but for the Input. It cuts off everything other than the path described, and that is the only thing sent into the lambda. But it does not stop the input from being appeneded - so InputPath + ResultPath results in less being sent into the lambda, but everything all together on the exit

There isn't really a loop logic like the one you describe however - Task and State Machine definitions are static directions, not dynamic logic.

You can simply handle it inside the lambda. This is kinda the preferred method. HOWEVER if you do this, then you should use a combination of OutputPath and ResultPath to 'cut off' the input, having replaced the various fields of the incoming event with whatever you want before returning it at the end.